# ThemeNegotiator not working for admin pages

Tags: 8, theme-negotiation

I'm trying to use the ThemeNegotiator to change the theme of the add and edit pages of one content type. I've followed the following very extensive posts/blogs.

[Don't use admin theme for adding editing specific content type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277095/dont-use-admin-theme-for-adding-editing-specific-content-type)

[Dynamic theme switching in Drupal 8](https://jimconte.com/blog/web/dynamic-theme-switching-in-drupal-8)

[Soft launching your new drupal theme](https://dri.es/soft-launching-your-new-drupal-theme)

[Choose your theme dynamically Drupal 8](https://www.webomelette.com/choose-your-theme-dynamically-drupal-8-theme-negotiation)

I have a user that is allowed to see the Admin theme `seven`, but for one content type `documenten` I want him to see the front-end theme `svds`. I'm able to get this to work for front-end pages but not for admin pages. What I think is that the `applies` part doesn't match on the add and edit pages. So it doesn't know it's on a `documenten` content type. Does anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Module structure:

```
theme_switcher
--src
----Theme
------SwitcherNegotiator.php
--theme_switcher.info.yml
--theme_switcher.services.yml
```

theme_switcher.info.yml:

```
name: Theme Switcher
type: module
description: 'Switch theme for specific Content Type'
package: SVDS
core: 8.x
```

theme_switcher.services.yml:

```
services:
    theme.negotiator.theme_switcher:
        class: Drupal\theme_switcher\Theme\SwitcherNegotiator
        tags:
          - { name: theme_negotiator, priority: -50 }
```

SwitcherNegotiator.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\theme_switcher\Theme\SwitcherNegotiator
 */

namespace Drupal\theme_switcher\Theme;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatchInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeNegotiatorInterface;

class SwitcherNegotiator implements ThemeNegotiatorInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match)
    {
        // Use this theme on a certain route.
        $node = $route_match->getParameter('node');
        if (!is_null($node) && $node instanceof \Drupal\node\Entity\Node) {
            return $node->getType() == 'documenten';
        }

        // apply default theme
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function determineActiveTheme(RouteMatchInterface $route_match)
    {
        // Here you return the actual theme name.
        return 'svds';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The admin theme negotiator is tagged with a priority of -40:

*user.services.yml*

```
  theme.negotiator.admin_theme:
    class: Drupal\user\Theme\AdminNegotiator
    arguments: ['@current_user', '@config.factory', '@entity_type.manager', '@router.admin_context']
    tags:
      - { name: theme_negotiator, priority: -40 }
```

So you have to use at least -39, since the first negotiator returning a theme name wins and on an admin page this core service will return the admin theme.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this solves the problem when editing a node. But not when adding one. So `/node/add/documenten` still shows the admin theme.

Comment: That's a different route `/node/add/{node_type}`, so you have to check for the node type as route parameter.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/249297/47547 for a code example which covers both cases.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks.