# How to get node information in RouteSubscriberBase::alterRoutes

Tags: routes, 9, theme-negotiation

what I'm trying to achieve is, for some specific nodes, to set the admin theme.

How can I get node information in this class?

```php
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.canonical')) {
      $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
      // dpm($node); - this will be null
      if ($nid == 123) {
        $route->setOption('_node_operation_route', TRUE);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

`$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');` does not work; `$route->getPath()` returns `'/node/{node}'`.

Comment: As you said $route->getPath() will return /node/{node} ,by using explode function you can get the node id as a array format ,or try in such way $entity = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
if ($entity instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) { // Check if it is a node
  $nid = $node->id(); // You also have the node object right here
}

Comment: You'll never be able to get a node ID here - this event will only fire when caches are cleared or when a module is enabled.

Comment: If you want to choose a different theme for specific nodes you need a custom theme negotiator. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/281447/themenegotiator-not-working-for-admin-pages